# why can not update my application in android

Tags: android, android-update-app

recently I get `Installed blocked : The app permissions error` error when updating my application(in app updating).
I know my app signatures are same because I can install new app manually.

can some know why this happen?

Do you think I need to grant `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` while I granted `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`? if yes can explain deference of both?

**Note:** my application updated correctly in many devices!! but in some devices(`android Version: 5.1.1`) have problem!!!

Answer (score 2):

The INSTALL_PACKAGES permission allows an application to install packages. It is not for use by third-party applications.

Developers of apps that require the ability to download and install other apps via the Package Installer may need to make some changes. If an app uses a targetSdkLevel of 26 or above and prompts the user to install other apps, the manifest file needs to include the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.

Read more here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-it-safer-to-get-apps-on-android-o.html?m=1

Comment: thanks for response. can you tell me some suggestion why i can not update my application?!